# Where does Install-Module <module name> fetch modules from?

Tags: powershell

Using the Windows PowerShell shell, when I type

```
Install-Module <module name>
```

...where exactly on the Internet does the host go to fetch that module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running that command will connect to all repositories currently configured on the machine to search for the module.

Run `Get-PSRepository` for the current list and addresses for them.

```
PS C:\ Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Trusted              https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```

By default Microsoft Powershell Gallery - PSGallery - should be configured. If you've lost this setting it can be reset using:

```
Register-PSRepository -Default
```